# update phpmyadmin in EC2 amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I would like to know how to update **phpmyadmin** in amazon EC2, 
I have the `pem`. permissions for. I access the server without any problems,

'm like:

```
ssh-i my_serveur.pem ubuntu @ **. **. *. **
```

then:

```
cd / var / ..
```

But I do not see or move the **phpmyadmin** folder? 
Even better, is there a way (in line command) to update **phpmyadmin**?

Thank you to all

EDIT :

thank you Neal 
I told you, but I still do not see my answer ... 
so I edit my post;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in a Linux instance (whether in EC2 or not), from the command-line you can update packages like this:

For Redhat / Cent / Amazon Linux:

```
  sudo yum update
```

For Debian / Ubuntu:

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or if you want only to update that single package, you could do this:

```
  sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

and you'll get prompted for any confirmations or dependencies, etc. before the update runs. You will need sudo powers to run these commands.

Comment: For Redhat / Cent / Amazon Linux, you need to do: `sudo yum update install phpmyadmin`. However, for EC2 instance, the version is way older than the latest version, due to repository restriction.